# asp.net core MapControllerRoute does not match my route (authorisation is not fired)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Im using ASP.NET Core 3.1.5 and I have the following code:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "UserAccessRoutes",
                pattern:  "UserAccess/GetUsers/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "UserAccess", action = "GetUsers" }
            ).RequireAuthorization(new AuthoriseAttribute("Test"));


            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
        });
        
        
public class UserAccessController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IUsersService usersService;

    public UserAccessController(IUsersService usersService)
    {
        this.usersService = usersService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<UserServerDto> GetUsers(long serverId)
    {
        ...somecode
    }
}
```

When I call http://localhost:5000/useraccess/getusers?id=10 the GetUsers is called but it skips the custom authorisation attribute. Why it doesn't match the first map route?

Comment: Have you added a call to `app.UseAuthorization()` in your `Startup` class?

Comment: Yes I did. If I use the Authorise Attribute directly in the controller method it works. When I use it like in my post authorization does not work.

Comment: And what's your code for defining the `Test` policy? Also, I notice the attribute is `Authorise`, with an `s`, so is this a custom attribute?

Comment: I just found out that the overload for ```RequireAuthorization``` accepts my call as ```IAuthorizeData``` overload thus it is checking the policy and the custom attribute that I have and uses custom permissions does not work.

Comment: As far as I know, the `new AuthoriseAttribute("Test")` means it will use Test policy. Have you set the  Test policy? If possible, please post related  Test policy codes. Besides, if you want to use `RequireAuthorization ` to work with policy, I suggest you could directly set the policy name as parameter like this `.RequireAuthorization("Test")`.